# Converting HashString from C to JS

Tags: javascript, c++, c, firefox-addon

I'm trying to convert this function from the Mozilla Firefox code base, it's called `HashString`. It calls a bunch of functions which are all in this file: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/mfbt/HashFunctions.h#294

So these are the C functions it calls:

```
static const uint32_t kGoldenRatioU32 = 0x9E3779B9U;

MOZ_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT inline uint32_t
HashString(const wchar_t* aStr)
{
  return detail::HashUntilZero(aStr);
}

template<typename T>
uint32_t
HashUntilZero(const T* aStr)
{
  uint32_t hash = 0;
  for (T c; (c = *aStr); aStr++) {
    hash = AddToHash(hash, c);
  }
  return hash;
}

MOZ_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT inline uint32_t
AddToHash(uint32_t aHash, A* aA)
{
  /*
   * You might think this function should just take a void*.  But then we'd only
   * catch data pointers and couldn't handle function pointers.
   */

  static_assert(sizeof(aA) == sizeof(uintptr_t), "Strange pointer!");

  return detail::AddUintptrToHash<sizeof(uintptr_t)>(aHash, uintptr_t(aA));
}

inline uint32_t
AddUintptrToHash<8>(uint32_t aHash, uintptr_t aValue)
{
  /*
   * The static cast to uint64_t below is necessary because this function
   * sometimes gets compiled on 32-bit platforms (yes, even though it's a
   * template and we never call this particular override in a 32-bit build).  If
   * we do aValue >> 32 on a 32-bit machine, we're shifting a 32-bit uintptr_t
   * right 32 bits, and the compiler throws an error.
   */
  uint32_t v1 = static_cast<uint32_t>(aValue);
  uint32_t v2 = static_cast<uint32_t>(static_cast<uint64_t>(aValue) >> 32);
  return AddU32ToHash(AddU32ToHash(aHash, v1), v2);
}

inline uint32_t
AddU32ToHash(uint32_t aHash, uint32_t aValue)
{
  return kGoldenRatioU32 * (RotateBitsLeft32(aHash, 5) ^ aValue);
}

inline uint32_t
RotateBitsLeft32(uint32_t aValue, uint8_t aBits)
{
  MOZ_ASSERT(aBits < 32);
  return (aValue << aBits) | (aValue >> (32 - aBits));
}
```

And here is my js code:

```
function HashString(aStr, aLength) {
    // moz win32 hash function

    if (aLength) {
        console.error('NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED');
        throw Components.results.NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;
    } else {
        return HashUntilZero(aStr);
    }   
}

function HashUntilZero(aStr) {
    var hash = 0;
    //for (T c; (c = *aStr); aStr++) {
    for (var c=0; c<aStr.length; c++) {
        hash = AddToHash(hash, aStr.charCodeAt(c));
    }

    return hash;
}

function AddToHash(aHash, aA) {
    //return detail::AddU32ToHash(aHash, aA);
    //return AddU32ToHash(aHash, aA);

    //return detail::AddUintptrToHash<sizeof(uintptr_t)>(aHash, aA);
    return AddUintptrToHash(aHash, aA);
}

function AddUintptrToHash(aHash, aValue) {
    //return AddU32ToHash(aHash, static_cast<uint32_t>(aValue));
    return AddU32ToHash(aHash, aValue);
}

function AddU32ToHash(aHash, aValue) {
    var kGoldenRatioU32 = 0x9E3779B9;
    return (kGoldenRatioU32 * (RotateBitsLeft32(aHash, 5) ^ aValue));
}

function RotateBitsLeft32(aValue, aBits) {
    // MOZ_ASSERT(aBits < 32);
    return (aValue << aBits) | (aValue >> (32 - aBits));
}

console.log(HashString('C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\aksozfjt.Unnamed Profile 10')); // should return 3181739213
```

This isn't working right, doing `HashString('C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\aksozfjt.Unnamed Profile 10')` should return to me `3181739213` however it's not. It keeps returning to me: `-159266146140`

Comment: in your for loop at `HashUntillZero` you are incrementing the string instead  of the counter, this is messing up the rest of the code.

Comment: Ah thank you very much @Entoarox ! I missed that, I fixed it but now its giving me `-159266146140` when I should be getting `3181739213` :(

Comment: you did not copy the last hex for the golden ratio either, but that one is a rather easy mistake, missed it myself the first time. Edit: C++/C might also handle right-shifting differently from javascript, but idk that for certain.

Comment: Thanks so much @Entoarox can you please help me understand that last hex on the golden ratio, I dont understand.

Comment: C:`static const uint32_t kGoldenRatioU32 = 0x9E3779B9U;`,JS:`var kGoldenRatioU32 = 0x9E3779B9;` Hopefully that makes it clear?

Comment: Thanks @Entoarox but if I stick the U on the end it throws `SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal`, I think the `U` in the C is telling it to be unsinged int.

Comment: I've checked the type declarations and I believe the issue is there, javascript does not have a unsigned 32bit integer, only the signed one, you would have to convert the signed 32bit integer into a normal javascript `number` (As that is not limited by 32bits) before using it in `AddU32ToHash`

Comment: Thanks @Entoarox this helps me a lot in understanding the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's implement a more minimal C++ version first, which also dumps intermediate values which we can later compare.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

static const uint32_t gr = 0x9E3779B9U;
template<typename T>
static uint32_t add(uint32_t hash, T val) {
  const uint32_t rv = gr * (((hash << 5) | (hash >> 27)) ^ val);
  cerr << dec << setw(7) << (uint32_t)val << " " << setw(14) << rv << " " << hex << rv << endl;
  return rv;
}

int main() {
  const auto text = string("C:\\Users\\Vayeate\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\aksozfjt.Unnamed Profile 10");
  uint32_t rv = 0;
  for (auto c: text) {
    rv = add(rv, c);
  }
  cout << "Result: " << dec << setw(14) << rv << " " << hex << rv << endl;
}
```

`Result:     3181739213 bda57ccd`, so we're on the right track.

Now, for some Javascript:

- `GetNativePath` returns an `nsAutoCString` aka. 8-bit string, by converting the internal 16-bit string to UTF-8.
- Javascript does not actually know about 32-bit unsigned integers, just 32-bit signed integers, but there are some dirty tricks (mainly the `>>> 0` "unsigned cast").
- 32-bit unsigned multiplication does not work, but we can actually implement that operation ourselves.
- Properly escaping the backslashes `\` in your test string also helps ;)

Putting these things together, I arrived at the following function, which seems to produce correct results.

```
/**
 * Javascript implementation of
 * https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/0cefb584fd1a/mfbt/HashFunctions.h
 * aka. the mfbt hash function.
 */ 
let HashString = (function() {
  // Note: >>>0 is basically a cast-to-unsigned for our purposes.
  const encoder = new TextEncoder("utf-8");
  const kGoldenRatio = 0x9E3779B9;

  // Multiply two uint32_t like C++ would ;)
  const mul32 = (a, b) => {
    // Split into 16-bit integers (hi and lo words)
    let ahi = (a >> 16) & 0xffff;
    let alo = a & 0xffff;
    let bhi = (b >> 16) & 0xffff
    let blo = b & 0xffff;
    // Compute new hi and lo seperately and recombine.
    return (
      (((((ahi * blo) + (alo * bhi)) & 0xffff) << 16) >>> 0) +
      (alo * blo)
    ) >>> 0;
  };

  // kGoldenRatioU32 * (RotateBitsLeft32(aHash, 5) ^ aValue);
  const add = (hash, val) => {
    // Note, cannot >> 27 here, but / (1<<27) works as well.
    let rotl5 = (
      ((hash << 5) >>> 0) |
      (hash / (1<<27)) >>> 0
    ) >>> 0;
    return mul32(kGoldenRatio, (rotl5 ^ val) >>> 0);
  }

  return function(text) {
    // Convert to utf-8.
    // Also decomposes the string into uint8_t values already.
    let data = encoder.encode(text);

    // Compute the actual hash
    let rv = 0;
    for (let c of data) {
      rv = add(rv, c | 0);
    }
    return rv;
  };
})();

let res = HashString('C:\\Users\\Vayeate\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\aksozfjt.Unnamed Profile 10');
console.log(res, res === 3181739213);
```

Might not be the most efficient implementation, but well, it works at least ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler way

```
var file = new FileUtils.File('C:\\Users\\Vayeate\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\aksozfjt.Unnamed Profile 10');
file.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHashable);
console.log(file.hashCode === 3181739213);
```

Comment: Right... `nsIFile` is `nsIHashable`, good catch. So for `nsIFile` compatible paths, this one will work just fine and is simpler indeed.

Comment: Hey paa and @nmaier , when I copy paste this code, it's giving me `3375393251` it should be `3181739213`, im sure about this because thats the `browser.taskbar.lastgroupid` value for my profile. That's really weird do you know whats up?

Comment: The hashCode **is** 3181739213. Probably lastgroupid doesn't hold the value of hashCode.

Comment: Thanks paa, Is there a similar way to hashCode method to get 3181739213? Like nmaier method above returns correct? This is how lasgroupid is set: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/widget/windows/WinTaskbar.cpp#264 `id.AppendInt(HashString(path));`

Comment: @Noitidart, both nmaier's implementation and nsIHashable return the same result, at least that's what happens with the example. And even if they differed, I doubt that the fault would be on nsIHashable's side. The code you point to, shows that the hash string of the path is used conditionally. Does your code consider these conditions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean :( I copied your example and i copied nmaiers and edited his string to match yours. His spit out 318.. and this way is putting out 337.. :( I just double tested it again :(

Comment: Here's youtube video showing what i did: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4kiJ2exc8QE

Comment: On my system it returns 3181739213. On the other hand, on my system this path does not exist. Can you check if the hashCode for `C:\\Users\\Unknown\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\aksozfjt.Unnamed Profile 10` is 3103912233 ?

Comment: @nmaier and paa Whoops forgive that I missed your message and didn't want to pester. I really appreciate you trying to follow up on this. I'll tst it right now. Yep just tested both HashString and this return to me same for `C:\\Users\\Unknown\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\aksozfjt.Unnamed Profile 10`, however this path doesnt exist for me either. I tried it with existing paths and `file.hashCode` doesnt match `HashString`: http://i.imgur.com/LSrYSjl.png

Comment: How i test this for correctness is check pref val of `browser.taskbar.lastgroupid` after creating and setting `taskbar.grouping.useprofile` to true.

Comment: A very very interesting note. After I delete the file at target path, then hashCode returns correct for the first situation in the image i posted in my previous comment. So `C:\\Users\\Vayeate\\Desktop\\abs path prof` is correct after deleting the folder O_O edit: image showing evidence: http://i.imgur.com/kBwbGDc.png

Comment: Must restart the browser after setting the pref of `taskbar.grouping.useprofile`